# Command Line Program with Incorrect Ordering

Tags: c, bash, scripting

I am currently have a C program that asks the user for input prompts.

My program has a "Please enter: " as the user prompt.

I am currently trying to automate this with a bash script, but the input
ordering keeps getting messed up.

In my bash script, if I try to do `echo "ls" | ./program_executable`, I get

```
Program output
Please enter:
```

When what I want is:

```
Please enter: ls
Program output
```

Are there any other methods I could use to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem? Do you by chance print to both stdout and stderr?

Comment: you can use [tag:expect] or similar tools.

Comment: When you run the program interactively, after you type "ls<ENTER>" the string is flushed to the screen. When redirected from the command-line there is no "<ENTER>", so just `fflush(stdout);` to force output manually.

Answer (score 1):

`fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()` should solve the problem.